# Delete action method using Ajax MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-ajax

i'm trying to implement a single page application in mvc.net using ajax , i'm facing problem with implementing the delete service , here is my Delete action method :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        db.Movies.Remove(movie);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

here is my Delete onclick function :

```
 function Delete(id){
        //here i want to take delete the row with it specifc id ,

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ ID: id }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function () {
               // alert("Data has been deleted.");
                LoadData();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while deleting data");
            }
        });
```

this delete should be called when the delete button is clicked, which is created by the load Data function :

```
function LoadData() {
    $("#tblStudent tbody tr").remove();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("getStudent")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: '' },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = '';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var rows = "<tr>"
                + "<td class='prtoducttd' id='MovieID'>" + item.ID  + "</td>"
                + "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + item.Name + "</td>"
                + "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + item.Type + "</td>"
                    + "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + item.date + "</td>"
                    + "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + "<input class='btn btn- primary'  name='submitButton' id='btnEdit' value='Edit'  onclick='delete' type='button'>"+ "<input class='btn btn- primary' name='submitButton' id='btnDel' value='Delete' type='button'>" + "</td>"
                + "</tr>";
                $('#tblStudent tbody').append(rows);
            });
        },
```

how to pass the id of the movie to the delete function when the button is clicked ?

Comment: You have multiple problems including invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes). Get rid of `onclick='delete'` and use `$('#tblStudent').on('click', '.delete', function() { var id = $(this).data('id'); ...` and then change the button to `"<button class="delete" data-id=" + item.ID + ">Delete</button>"`

Comment: And why in the world are you calling `LoadData()` in the delete function. Just remove the associated element from the DOM. There is no point degrading performance by downloading all the data again

Comment: i''m just beginner trying to learn ,, thank u very much i think i get your point... @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parameters in controller action method and in data : {} of ajax call must be the same, as you are using  public ActionResult Delete(int id) in Controller you must use id : id in ajax call.

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }), //use id here
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
           // alert("Data has been deleted.");
            LoadData();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error while deleting data");
        }
    });
```

second thing, it is not a good idea to write whole row in load data function in single var row variable. you can declare var row = ''; before each loop and then can do like this.

```
var rows = '';
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            rows += "<tr>",
            rows += '<td>' + item.MovieID+ '</td>'
            //and so on.............and lastly use .html instead of append

            $('#tblStudent tbody').html(rows);
        });
```

for reference, refer this link :- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-in-asp-net-mvc-using-ajax-and-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

The ajax needs some modifications. The name of the parameters and method name should exactly match in controller and ajax.

```js
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ControllerName/Delete',// same case sensitive action name
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }), //small letter id, same as in controller parameter
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function () {
               // alert("Data has been deleted.");
                LoadData();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while deleting data");
            }
```

If still the delete action not getting called, remove the json.stringify and just pass 'id': idval in data.